# How to include dropped information about groups in dataframe series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe and I want to include all information based on the "Individual ID" after condition(s) is met.

```
import pandas as pd


data = [['A-1', 'Birth','0'],
        ['A-1','Sickle cell',"5"],['A-1', 'Lung cancer',"25"],
        ['A-1','Death','35'],['A-2', 'Birth', '0'],
        ['A-2','Sarcoma','10'],['A-2', 'Melanoma','19'], 
        ['A-2', 'Current Age', '20'], ['A-3', 'Birth',"0"],
        ['A-3','Sickle cell','25'],['A-3', "Skin cancer", "29"], 
        ['A-3', "Current Age", '40']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["Individual ID", "Diagnosis","Age"])

print df
```

I have tried the following code:

```
first = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby("Individual ID").filter(lambda g: g["Individual ID"].size > 3))

breast1 = ((first["Repeat Instance"] == 1) & (first["Diagnosis"] != "Sickle cell"))  

after = first[breast1]

print after
```

After running the code, I get this:

```
  Individual ID    Diagnosis Age Repeat Instance
1           A-1  Sickle cell   5               1
9           A-3  Sickle cell  25               1
```

I want to get the rest of the information for individuals A-1 and A-3 (birth, current age, other diagnosis) but have not been able to figure it out.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the help all. I managed to get the information I wanted by matching the Individual IDs in the results I got into the main dataframe using the .isin method of pandas.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following approach:

You can create an additional column with the counts as follows:

`df['size'] = df.groupby("Individual ID")["Individual ID"].transform('size')`

After this you can create a variable storing the conditions you need to subset the dataframe:

`cond = (df['size'] > 3) & (df['Diagnosis']!="Sickle cell")`

`subset = df[cond].copy()`

Answer (score 0):

I answer in pythonic way

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["Individual ID", "Diagnosis","Age"])
search = '0'
a = list(filter(lambda x:x[2]==search,data))
print (a)
```

It returns the list that third element is 0 and you can customize it